# Why Xeon x3430 running at only 1.20 GHZ even on full workload?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, xeon

In our office we have two Dell PowerEdge R310 Servers which have Xeon X3430 CPUs and should run at 2.40 GHz. Both have Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise installed. Unfortunately one of them is operating at only 1.20 GHz even at full workload!

[image: see here]

**What should I do to utilize the full CPU power as shown here?**

[image: as shown here]

Comment: What did Dell support say when you called them? It could be a number of things, including cooling.

Comment: I didn't because our support period has finished.But I am sure that its not a cooling issue.

Comment: @Analoggenhacker How are you sure about that? Do you have thermal data to back up that claim?

Comment: You should check the CPU core temps, either with software or in the BIOS. I wonder if you can restrict CPU performance in the OS.

Comment: check your power plans in Windows and the Bios

Comment: @TheCleaner That looks promising! let me check.

Comment: @TheCleaner I checked the power plan on OS,and found a custom plan which cooling policy was set to "passive",now i changed that to "active" and then reboot the server,but that did not fix the problem..

Comment: @Tim  I checked the power plan on OS,and found a custom plan which cooling policy was set to "passive",now i changed that to "active" and then reboot the server,but that did not fix the problem..

Comment: As I said earlier, check the temperatures when the server is working hard. I use [Open Hardware Monitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/) but Dell may have their own utilities that does this.

Comment: @Tim temperature is normal,46 max on 100% cpu load.